# How can i access Client data into custom Normalizer (Symfony 4)

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to create a custom normalizer, but I cannot access to my current user using API Platform.

When I try to load my Client class, this is empty. I tried to method using the API Platform's documentation, but the retreived token is empty too.

Do you have any tip to get my current user ? Thanks

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Stock;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class StockAttributeNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

public function normalize($topic, $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($topic, $format, $context);

    var_dump($data);

    return $data;
}

public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    return $data instanceof Stock;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you register it as a service and added tag `serializer.normalizer`?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html#registering-it-in-your-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to inject TokenInterface on your class ?

```php
public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, ObjectNormalizer $normalizer, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->token = $token;
    }
```

Then you can use `$token->getUser()` to retrieve your current user.

if you don't have a user then you don't use your API with authentication. See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/